# Xpath response always returns null

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to learn Scrapy:
this is the url I am using to scrape price information on this bag.
"https://www.net-a-porter.com/ca/en/product/1100692/chloe/roy-day-small-leather-and-suede-shoulder-bag"

there are other values that are also returning null but for the base case lets just go with price

```
 yield {
        'price' : response.xpath("//nap-price[@class='product-price']/span[@itemprop='price']/text()").extract_first(),}
```

the return value is always null. However when I run it past dev tools it tells me string should match

other strings I've tried:

```
"//nap-price[@class='product-price']/span[@class='full-price style-scope nap-price']/text()"

"//nap-price[@class='product-price']/span[2]/text()"

//nap-price[@class='product-price']/span[2]/@content
```

and a few others that work in dev tools but always return a null response when run with scrapy what's going on here? I've tried getting really specific as well as general with my match strings but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't always trust in the "Inspect element" in devtools because it shows the final HTML, after it was rendered by Javascript.
One tip is copy the price, say "1850", open the page source code with right click "View Page Source" (in Firefox, something like this in Chrome) and search for the price on it to see where the source of the information is.

You will find this tag with useful information:

```
<meta class="product-data"
    data-designer-name="Chloe"
    data-designer-id="122"
    data-analytics-key="Roy Day small leather and suede shoulder bag"
    data-pid="1100692"
    data-breadcrumb-names="Bags / Shoulder Bags / Cross Body"
    data-breadcrumb-keys="Bags / Shoulder_Bags / Cross_Body"
    data-breadcrumb-ids="1282 / 1335 / 6012"
    data-sold-out="false"
    data-price-full="185000"
    data-price="185000"
/>
```

So you can write a css selector like this:

```
response.css('meta.product-data::attr(data-price)').extract_first()
```

Or with xpath:

```
response.xpath('//meta[@class="product-data"]/@data-price').extract_first()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's awesome. I completely forgot I can check the meta-data of the page for info as well. Thank you for the info!